Carto DataForm BigQuery external resource permissions error but workbench functions
I'm getting this carto error in DataForm:
Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Error getting metadata for external code resource, please verify you have provided a valid path and/or that you have access to the resource: gs://my-carto-project-name/carto/libs/carto_analytics_toolbox.js.

The code runs correctly but this error hangs there in the dataform editor and annoyingly blocks all debugging in DataForm for this script.
Is it something to do with the way I am using the carto project/dataset location string?
I am currently running it like this:
`${main_config.CARTO_PROJECT_ID}`.carto.H3_FROMGEOGPOINT(start_point, 12)
When this is compiled into the query it looks like this:
`my-carto-project-name`.carto.H3_FROMGEOGPOINT(start_point, 12)

CARTO grant permission to access Analytics Toolbox procedures and external functions to credentials used to create connections.
Please create a connection in CARTO using the same service account or user account that you're using to run that query in Dataform.

Thanks - yes I found another service account to run it on that was like:
my-carto-project-name-b8fb
just weird that it worked despite the error previously
